# Use Unity's il2cpp.exe alone

Tags: .net, unity-game-engine, il2cpp

Can I use Unity's il2cpp.exe alone to convert any .Net Framework Compiled IL binary?
for example, Windows Forms?

Sorry if this is a weird question,
Recently I found the binary compiled with IL bytecode could be restored almost the same as the original source code.
So I was just looking for a way to convert IL code to native machine code.

Comment: Well technically IL2CPP converts IL to _c++ code_ then the c++ compiler steps in to compile the latter to native code.

Comment: I doubt you can use a WinForms form (or any other WIN32 GUI app) in Unity because Unity does not concern itself with the Windows Message Pump.  Without it, GUI apps made using WIN32 or .NET WinForms fail to paint their windows, process keyboard or mouse input amongst other things.  It's kind of like trying to make a console app display a non-modal window, _sure you can do it but it's much easier to make a GUI app in the first place_.  If you are just after native code conversion and don't care about Unity check out UWP apps

Comment: @MickyD Thank you for your opinion. I'll check it out.

Comment: My pleasure good sir